# passing in two values into a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm writing an action for react-redux and I'm trying to pass in two vars into the function, one `dispatch`, and the other `hosts`. The problem is, `host` is console.log'ing as a function and not a value.

my code:

```
export function hostSelected (hostSelected) {

    console.log(" host is2: ", hostSelected)

    let host = hostSelected

    return function(dispatch, host) {

        console.log(" host is: ", host)
       return eSclient.search({

            index: "sdpjmx",
            type: "kafkajmx",
            body:  {
                    "size": 0,
                    "aggs" : {
                        "topics" : {
                            "terms" : {
                              "field" : host,
                              "size": 500
                            }
                        }
                    },  
                    "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "filter": [
                        {
                          "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                              "gte": "now-1d"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                }

        }).then(topics => {

            dispatch(loadTopicsSuccess(topics));

        }).catch(error => {
            throw(error);
        });
    };

}
```

and the console log output is this:

```
console.log(" host is2: ", hostSelected)
host is2: hostname123

console.log(" host is: ", host)
host is:  function getState() {
    return currentState;
  }
```

why is `host` returning a function?

-------EDIT--------

I changed it to the following but I'm still getting the same results....

```
export function hostSelected (hostSelection) {

    console.log(" host is2: ", hostSelection)

    let host = hostSelection

    return function(dispatch, host) {

        console.log(" host is: ", host)
        console.logt("host function: ", host())

       return eSclient.search({

            index: "sdpjmx",
            type: "kafkajmx",
            body:  {
                    "size": 0,
                    "aggs" : {
                        "topics" : {
                            "terms" : {
                              "field" : host,
                              "size": 500
                            }
                        }
                    },  
                    "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "filter": [
                        {
                          "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                              "gte": "now-1d"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                }

        }).then(topics => {

            dispatch(loadTopicsSuccess(topics));

        }).catch(error => {
            throw(error);
        });
    };

}
```

--

```
console.logt("host function: ", host())
host function: Object {topic_drpDwn: Array(0), initial_drpDwn: Object} //this is the current state object it returns
```

Comment: You seem to have a bad habit of naming your function parameters the same name as other variables. It's best to use unique names, in order to prevent confusion from variable shadowing.

Comment: you are setting let host = hostSelected equal to the whole function. Change the function name or simply the parameter to "host".

Comment: I tried to change the names but that didn't seem to work either....I made an edit to show what I did...

Comment: what does `console.log(" host is2: ", hostSelected)` return?

Comment: what the heck is "console.logt" ?

Comment: what is the purpose of `let host = hostSelected` as the 5th line - it isn't used anywhere. It _is shadowed_ by a parameter name using the same identifier.

Answer (score 0):

It is a 'syntax error' if you will... in the example below, the first log (`1`) will log the function code; `function hi(){ return 'Hello world!'; }` , and the second (`2`) will log `Hello world!`

```
function hi () {
    return 'Hello world!';
}

console.log(hi); //  1

console.log(hi()); //  2
```

So if you change you line to `console.log(host());` it should work.

Comment: host is not a function though, its just a parameter...I don't understand why its showing up as a function...

Comment: Hmm, how do you create the instance of the passed parameter before calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

Your action creators in redux-thunk can return functions, and those functions will then be called with two arguments, `dispatch` will be the first, and `getState` will be the second - both of these are functions.  When you are logging `host`, the function you are seeing is the `getState` function passed by redux-thunk.

The arguments passed to the action creator by you i.e. `hostSelected` will also be available to the returned function, inside a closure.  This means you can write your code as:

```
export function hostSelected (host) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        eSclient.search({
            index: "sdpjmx",
            type: "kafkajmx",
            body:  {
                    "size": 0,
                    "aggs" : {
                        "topics" : {
                            "terms" : {
                              "field" : host,
                              "size": 500
                            }
                        }
                    },  
                    "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "filter": [
                        {
                          "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                              "gte": "now-1d"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                }
        }).then(topics => {
            dispatch(loadTopicsSuccess(topics));
        }).catch(error => {
            throw(error);
        });
    };
}
```

Or with ES6 lambda/arrow functions:

```
export const hostSelected = ( host ) => ( dispatch ) => {
    eSclient.search({
                index: "sdpjmx",
                type: "kafkajmx",
                body:  {
                        "size": 0,
                        "aggs" : {
                            "topics" : {
                                "terms" : {
                                  "field" : host,
                                  "size": 500
                                }
                            }
                        },  
                        "query": {
                        "bool": {
                          "filter": [
                            {
                              "range": {
                                "@timestamp": {
                                  "gte": "now-1d"
                                }
                              }
                            }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                    }
            }).then(topics => {
                dispatch(loadTopicsSuccess(topics));
            }).catch(error => {
                throw(error);
            });
}
```